# What is the idea behind Schuhler Gambit?

Tags: opening, gambits

The Schuhler Gambit is a line in the Sokolsky Opening.

```
[FEN ""]

1. b4 c6 2.Bb2 a5 3.b5 cxb5 4.e4
```

White gives away their b-pawn here. Stockfish claims this actually gives a small advantage to White, (although I analyzed only to depth 25) while bxa5 gives a small advantage to Black.

Why is it good and what is White's plan?

Comment: I'm very sorry for the pronoun - it was not intended at all.

Comment: I would assume that the reason for White having a slight is the fact that White's pieces will have much quicker development than Black's if Black tries to maintain the extra pawn

Comment: @Scounged Ah, I see, e4 attacks the b5 pawn with the bishop. Is it considered a pseudo-gambit like Queen's Gambit?

Comment: Its a real gambit. Black can play b5-b4

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Ah, yes, and analyzing with Stockfish again it seems to be the best move for Black - but why? And after that a3 looks like a necessary move for White, now or later - but why?

Comment: If Black doesn't hold onto the pawn, then Black will be behind in development, with no compensation at all. See for yourself.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Looks quite the reverse to me. If Black keeps the pawn he just wasted one move moving a flank pawn, have a very ugly pawn structure and is behind in development. Something like Nc6 would be much better. I'm an order of magnitude weaker to most members of this site anyway, so...

Comment: "Stockfish claims this actually gives a small advantage to White" Oh, it's 0.0 equality. Don't know what I was thinking at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trades off time and space for a side pawn that loses more time for black if they try to keep it.

c6 was not a good response for black on move 1

in the position shown master results show an 80% win rate (draws =1/2)
for white with zero losses

black would do far better with 1 ...   d5 e5 or nf6